# scraper is unable to switch inputs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to login to a website using a selenium script i wrote. The problem im having is when it is logging in, its unable to locate the passwords input.

```
search = driver.find_element_by_id("clareity")
search.send_keys("user")
search.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="form-control lock"]')
search.send_keys("pass")
```

when it looks for the xpath it sends the keys into the username input, so when both keys get sent, in the user input on the site it show, "userPass" instead of putting the pass in the password input.

username input form:

```
<div class="form-control person" data-ph="LOGIN ID" id="clareity" contenteditable="true" required="" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"></div>
```

password input form:

```
<div class="form-control lock" data-ph="PASSWORD" id="security" contenteditable="true" required="" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"></div>
```

Comment: Based on the password input form, it looks like `password_input = driver.find_element_by_id("security")` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a variable for user, so you need to do the same for password

```
search = driver.find_element_by_id("clareity")
search.send_keys("user")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("security")
password.send_keys("pass")
```

Or don't use variables at all

```
driver.find_element_by_id("clareity").send_keys("user")
driver.find_element_by_id("security").send_keys("pass")
```

Comment: Technically the variable `search` can be overwritten without consequence, although it's arguably a bad practice. The real issue is likely the XPATH selector, which is a worse selector than `find_element_by_id` with the appropriate ID.

Comment: It's not being overwritten. With the way the OP code is structured, the `search.` notation won't work for password, it will be looking for an embedded xpath inside the `user` xpath already defined.  Needs to be separated

Comment: Ok so that worked, it found the element, but it didnt ```send_keys``` . And now i know why, on this site when you enter the password and reclick the input, the password clears and you have to reenter. it looks like when the script sends the pass it'll paste the password and disappear almost immediately